# Existence of the solution in Banach space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, banach-spaces

I have some difficulties with solving that problem:

Let $X$ be a linear space and $X= \left \{u \in C([0,\alpha]):\|u\|=\sup \frac{|u(x)|}{x}\right \}$.

We have a differential equation:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &y'=f(x,y) & \\ 
 &y(0)=y_{0}  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Where:

$|f(x,y)-f(x,z)|\leqslant  \frac{q}{x}|y-z|$ for all x $\in [0,\alpha]$, all real $y,z$ and some $q<1$.

Prove that there exsists exactly one solution in $X$.

I started with saying that $X$ is a Banach space. Then, defining operator $T:X \rightarrow X$:

$T(u)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t,u(t)+y_{0})dt$

I wanted to prove that for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , $T^n$ is a contraction. If it is, from Banach fixed point theorem I would have that $T$ has exactly one fixed point in $X$ and that would be the solution of the equation above. I just have no idea how to prove it. I tried to estimate $||T^n(u)(x)-T^n(v)(x)||$ but I couldn't come up with a good estimation. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to estimate $T^n$. It seems to me enough to prove $T$ is a contraction. For this we must use the particular norm of the space $X$. Note for all $t>0$,
\begin{equation}
\vert f(t,u(t)+y_0)-f(t,v(t)+y_0)\vert \leq \frac{q}{t}\vert u(t)-v(t)\vert\leq q\Vert u-v\Vert
\end{equation}
by the definition of the norm in $X$. Then for all $x>0$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\left\vert T(u)(x)-T(v)(x)\right\vert}x & = & \frac{\left\vert \int_0^{x}f(t,u(t)+y_0)-f(t,v(t)+y_0)dt \right\vert}{x}\\
& \leq & \frac{\int_0^x\left\vert f(t,u(t)+y_0)-f(t,v(t)+y_0)\right\vert dt}{x}\\
& \leq & \frac{\int_0^x\frac{q}{t}\left\vert u(t)-v(t)\right\vert dt}{x}\\
& \leq & \frac{q\int_0^x\left\Vert u-v \right\Vert dt}{x}\\
& \leq & q\Vert u-v \Vert
\end{eqnarray}
This implies $\Vert T(u)-T(v)\Vert \leq q\Vert u-v\Vert$, so $T$ is a contraction and by Banach fixed point theorem we conclude.

Comment: Thank you! But why did you use the $x_{0}$ index?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I will edit it. Glad to have been helpful : )